# Calculation of non-overlapping set (ordering set ) of minimum spanning trees

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

I am interested in calculating a set of non-overlapping minimum spanning trees of a weighted graph. For example to calculate the set of size 3. I calculate the maximum spanning tree, remove its edges and repeating.

When I use EdgeDelete, it takes an eternity (the graph is huge around 30,000 nodes and 40 millions of edges). So currently, I calculate  it in the following manner

```
SeedRandom[1]
arrayR = Append[Thread[RandomSample[Tuples[Range[1000], {2}], 5000] -> 
     RandomReal[1, 5000]], {_, _} -> 0];

weightedGraph=WeightedAdjacencyGraph[SparseArray[Most@arrayR, {1000, 1000}, ∞]];


 weG = weightedGraph;
resMatrix = AdjacencyMatrix[weG];
Table[minST = FindSpanningTree[weG];
  adjM1 = AdjacencyMatrix[minST];
  adjWG1 = AdjacencyMatrix[weG];
  weG = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[
    SparseArray[
     Most@ArrayRules[
       Chop[(adjWG1 - adjM1)]*WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[weG]], {1000, 
      1000}, \[Infinity]]];, {3}];
Chop[resMatrix - AdjacencyMatrix[weG]]
```

Any suggestion on how to speed up the calculation

Comment: "I am interested in calculating a set of non-overlapping minimum spanning trees of a weighted graph." I don't get what your aim is. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you.I  have a graph, and I interested in calculating a forest of k nonoverlapping trees (maybe each tree is a forest too, but for simplicity, I will call it a tree). 
The order of each tree in this set equal to its weight (the minimum spanning tree is the first, the second one is a minimum spanning tree in the original graph after removing the edges of the minimum spanning tree...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting. What took so long was the processing of `ArrayRules`; this generates an unpacked array of rules and this cannot be processed as quickly as the packed arrays of nonzero positions and nonzero values (see also how I generate the initial weighted adjacency matrix `A0` below).

Moreover, I observed that you reconstruct the sparse array only to set the default values to `∞`; this is seemingly required by `WeightedAdjacencyGraph` because it will generate a complete graph. As I just found out by pure chance, `WeightedAdjacencyGraph`, when called with a `SparseArray` as first argument allows for a *second* argument that allows us to specify that edges with weight `0.` shall be treated as nonexistent. Hence, we may use `SparseArray`s without any `∞` as follows:

```
SeedRandom[1]
A0 = SparseArray[
   RandomSample[Tuples[Range[1000], {2}], 5000] -> RandomReal[1, 5000],
   {1000, 1000}
   ];
G0 = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[A0, 0.];

G = G0;
A = WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[G];

graphs = Table[
   A = (SparseArray[
       Unitize[A] - AdjacencyMatrix[FindSpanningTree[G]]]) A;
   G = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[A, 0.],
   {3}
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.250941

Usually, I prefer to avoid `Graph`s at all and stick to adjacency matrices. The undocumented routine `` SparseArray`SpanningTree `` can compute spanning trees directly from a `SparseArray`; unfortunately, it seems to be unable to compute a *minimal* spanning tree...

Comment: A significant bottleneck in my competition is a using of WeightedAdjacencyGraph ( my graph is huge ~30k nodes 40 millions of edges).  I am confused why I need to create a graph to calculate MST and cant calculate it directly from the adjacency matrix. Of cause it possible to implement the Kruskal's algorithm, but I prefer not to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Have also a look into Szabolcs' `"IGraphM`" package. There is another algorithm `IGSpanningTree` that seems to be faster (but ignores direction of edges).